# R xts object - subset data points for 5 consecutive seconds

Tags: r, subset, xts, seconds

I have a large xts object and want to subset the seconds in the time column, but only if there is a sequence of minimum 5 consecutive seconds. I have up to 8 data points per second (which shouldn't be counted as 5 consecutive points as they are measured within the same second).

`And_sub_xts` is my xts object

```
> str(And_sub_xts)
An ‘xts’ object on 2010-04-09 20:32:56/2010-04-26 06:56:57 containing:
 Data: chr [1:164421, 1:11] "0.255416" "0.168836" "0.212126" "0.229442" "0.238100" "0.212126" "0.168836" ...
- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
 ..$ : NULL
 ..$ : chr [1:11] "CalSurge" "CalSway" "CalHeave" "Stat_Surge" ...
 Indexed by objects of class: [POSIXct,POSIXt] TZ: 
 xts Attributes:  
NULL
```

and the first 100 values for

`abs(diff(.indexsec(And_sub_xts))` are

56  8 23 34 40 40 41 42 25 27 34 35 38 38 40 40 41 56 59 59 19 19 20 20 20 20 **22 22 23 23 24 24 24 25 25 26 27 27 27 27 27 28 28** 30 30 30 37 38 40 40 41 44 44 46 46 47 48 51 52 54 54 54 54 55 56 59  1  4  4  4  6  6  6  6  7  7 11 12 12 **14 14 15 16 16 17 18 18 19 19** 21 21 22 22 23 23 25 25 26 26 26

I marked the  keeps in bold, so the subset should just consist of these data points.

I just realize that theorethically it could happen that there are some data points distributed like this

```
2010-04-09 20:32:20
2010-04-09 20:32:20
2010-04-09 20:32:21
2010-04-09 20:32:22
2010-04-09 20:32:22
2010-04-09 20:40:22
2010-04-09 22:52:23
2010-04-10 20:52:24
```

which wouldn't be 5 consecutive seconds, but you can't account for this with the .indexsec command - maybe anybody knows a way to go around this.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does the index of `And_sub_xts` contain sub-seconds, or is it just second resolution?

Comment: It's just second resolution. Thanks so much, your code works!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. `x` is sample data that contains index values with seconds equal to your first 100 values.

```
require(xts)
# sample data
s <- c(56, 8, 23, 34, 40, 40, 41, 42, 25, 27, 34, 35, 38, 38, 40, 
40, 41, 56, 59, 59, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 20, 22, 22, 23, 23, 24, 
24, 24, 25, 25, 26, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 30, 30, 30, 37, 
38, 40, 40, 41, 44, 44, 46, 46, 47, 48, 51, 52, 54, 54, 54, 54, 
55, 56, 59, 1, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 11, 12, 12, 14, 14, 
15, 16, 16, 17, 18, 18, 19, 19, 21, 21, 22, 22, 23, 23, 25, 25, 
26, 26, 26)
S <- cumsum(ifelse(c(0, diff(s)) < 0, 1, 0)) * 60 + s
x <- .xts(seq_along(S), S, tzone="UTC")
```

The basic idea is to aggregate your data to 1-second resolution, so you can use `rle` (run-length encoding) to find the consecutive 5-second observations. Then find the first and last timestamps of the sets of 5-second observations in your aggregated data, and then find the locations of those timestamps in your original data. Finally, use the locations of the timestamps in your original data to create sets of sequences you can use to subset the consecutive 5-second groups of observations.

```
# aggregate data to 1-second resolution
oneSec <- period.apply(x, endpoints(x, 'seconds'), identity) 
# find the runs of 5 or more consecutive one-second increments
consec <- rle(diff(.index(oneSec)))
gte5s <- consec$lengths >= 5
# get the location of the first obs of the run in the 1-second data
begLoc <- cumsum(c(1,consec$lengths))[gte5s]
endLoc <- begLoc + consec$lengths[gte5s]
# get the timestamp of the first and last obs from the original data
beg <- lapply(index(oneSec)[begLoc], function(i) first(x[i, which.i=TRUE]))
end <- lapply(index(oneSec)[endLoc], function(i) last(x[i, which.i=TRUE]))
# create index vector between each value in 'beg' and 'end'
loc <- unlist(mapply(seq, beg, end))
# subset original object using index vector
X <- x[loc,]
```

Comment: Hi, I've run the code now on two different xts objects (both have the same str as above). One works fine, the other one gives me the following Warning (followed by an Error later) `Warning message:
In begLoc + consec$lengths[gte5s] :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length` . Do you have an idea why that could be? I compared their structure and apart from the length it is really the same...

Comment: It's hard to say without actual data, but my guess is that there are no consecutive 5 second data points.